# How to fix RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED error when opening multiple MS Project files?

Tags: c#, ms-project

So im trying to open multiply MS Project files with data from database using MS Project interop. Start with code like this:

```
application = new MSProject.Application();
application.FileOpenEx(copyPath); // copy file from template
currentProject = application.ActiveProject;
```

And then working with its tasks:

```
MSProject.Task task = application.ActiveProject.Tasks.Add(item.Name);
InitTask(item, task, false); // fill items fields
```

It works fine with *one* file opened but i **cant** open *multiple* files because i get an exception:

> COMException was unhandled --- Call was rejected by callee. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

It throws at the first:

```
task.Name = obj.Name;
```

How can i fix it? Thanks!

Comment: There is not enough of the code shown to understand what you are trying to do and what might be causing the problem. Edit your question to show more of the code--for example how are you working with multiple project files? Advice--get your code working to update one file at a time and only once that works without error, change the code to work with multiple files at once. Also, do you really need to work with more than one file at a time?

Comment: As i already said: it works ok with one file opened (no errors) but when im trying to open another file with this code, i get an exception. Yes, i really need to work with more than one file, this is my task.
And i dont have any code that works with multiple project files... i just trying to open them and thats all. 
Update: i found another interop in inet to work with (prob older version or smth) and i can open 2 files without exception at first program launch but if i close them, open one file (works ok) and then open second file, i get an expection again...

Comment: is there any code that could help me to work with multiple project files? i just didnt find anything about it and this is why i dont have it in my program. maybe also theres a better way to get an interop to use? i just download it from inet or get from installed project from my pc. i also wanted to stop using interop because its too slow but i dont know what to use... i need to open an application, write data in it and when read after save to get all data to database

Comment: Suggest you [search for that error on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED); there are many ideas about what can cause that error and many possible solutions.